# Task to create flexible (dynamic memory allocation) array

Tags: c

We've been given a task to write a dynamic data structure in C. I'm still incredibly new to C and I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some pointers (lol) on what I'm doing wrong / what I should read more about.

Here's what I have so far:

**flexarray.h**

```
#ifndef FLEXARRAY_H
#define FLEXARRAY_H

typedef struct flexarrayrec flexarray;

flexarray *flexarray_new();
extern void flexarray_add(flexarray *a, char item);
extern void flexarray_set(flexarray *a, char item, int index);
extern char flexarray_get(flexarray *a, int index);
extern void flexarray_trim(flexarray *a);
extern void flexarray_print(flexarray *a);

#endif  /* FLEXARRAY_H */
```

**flexarray.c**

```
#include "flexarray.h"
#include "mylib.h"

#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 10

typedef struct flexarray{
    int size;
    int capacity;
    char *array;
};

flexarray *flexarray_new(){
    flexarray a;
    a->capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    a->size = 0;
    a->array = (char*) erealloc (a ,a->capacity * sizeof(char)); 
    return a;
}

void grow(flexarray a){
    a->capacity = a->capacity * 2;
    a->array = (int*) erealloc (a ,a->capacity * sizeof(int)); 
}

void flexarray_add(flexarray a, char item){
    if(a->size == a->capacity) grow(a);
    a->array[a->size - 1] = item;
    a->size++;    
}

void set(flexarray a, char c, int index){
    if(index < 0 || index  > a->size) return;
    a->array[index] = c;
}

char get(flexarray a, int index){
    if(index < 0 || index  > a->size) return;
    return a->array[index];
}


void flexarray_trim(flexarray a){
    if(a->size == a->capacity) return;
    a->capacity = a->size;
    a->array = (char*) erealloc (a, a->capacity * sizeof(char)); 
}

void flexarray_print(flexarray a){
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for(i = 0; i < a->size - 1; i++){
        printf("%c,", a->array[i]);
    }
    printf("%c]\n", a->array[i + 1]);
}
```

Thank you

**EDIT** Current compile log:

```
flexarray.c:10:1: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [enabled by default]
flexarray.c: In function 'flexarray_new':
flexarray.c:13:15: error: storage size of 'a' isn't known
flexarray.c: At top level:
flexarray.c:20:21: error: parameter 1 ('a') has incomplete type
flexarray.c:25:30: error: parameter 1 ('a') has incomplete type
flexarray.c:31:20: error: parameter 1 ('a') has incomplete type
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_Actual-Windows/flexarray.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: What is the question? What doesn't work? What doesn't compile?

Comment: You probably have to write a small main() function that will test your data structure. With that main you can test compilation and debug...

Comment: @eyalm I've excluded the main function, as it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @ssteinberg I'm getting a variety of compiling errors (which I'll add to the question now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void flexarray_add(flexarray a, char item){
    if(a->size == a->capacity) grow(a);
    a->array[a->size - 1] = item;
    a->size++;    
}
```

Should be:

```
void flexarray_add(flexarray *a, char item){
    if(a->size == a->capacity) grow(a);
    a->array[a->size] = item;
    a->size++;    
}
```

And:

```
void flexarray_print(flexarray a){
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for(i = 0; i < a->size - 1; i++){
        printf("%c,", a->array[i]);
    }
    printf("%c]\n", a->array[i + 1]);
}
```

Could be:

```
void flexarray_print(flexarray *a){
    int i;
    printf("[");
    for(i = 0; i < a->size; i++){
        printf("%c,", a->array[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n" );
}
```

Additional stylistic hints: for sizes and indexes try to use *unsigned* types as much as you can.

```
struct buff {
     size_t size;
     size_t used;
     char *data;
     };
```

The advantage of this is that attempts to use negative indices ( `b->data[b->used - 1] = item;` ) will fail misarably and fast  (instead of corrupting your memory slowly).

Also: you should test for the success/failure of realloc()

UPDATE2: it also appears there are some asterixes missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
flexarray *flexarray_new(){
    flexarray a;
    return a; // not a flexarray *
}
```

..and

```
a->array = (char*) erealloc (a ,a->capacity * sizeof(char));
```

What does 'erealloc()' do?

Comment: @wildplasser - there are quite a few to go at :)

Answer (score 0):

your `typedef`s are wrong -- you either want to write

```
typedef struct flexarray { ... } flexarray;
```

and remove the `typedef` from the header, or

```
 struct flexarrayrec { ... }; // no typedef
```

and keep the `tyepdef struct flexarrayrec flexarray;` in the header.

Comment: Brilliant, this was one of the main things that confused me.